# When opening a directory through command line, Sublime text opens two windows instead of one

Tags: sublimetext2

If I open a directory in Sublime using the command line (`subl path/to/my/folder/`), Sublime will open two instances: one with the directory I asked for, and another one with the directory I opened last time I used Sublime.  Any idea why ?

I don't know if it's revelant, but the problem occurs with Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are most likely using Sublime's save last session feature.

You can disable it:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Disable_automatic_loading_of_the_last_session

Answer (score 43):

*Thanks for the link, this worked for me.*

Do the following:
 Preferences > Settings - User

Once you enter the file 'Preferences.sublime.settings' add between the brackets following lines.

```
{
  "hot_exit": false,
  "remember_open_files": false
}
```

Comment: On windows, I wanted to make ST3 not open previous tabs when I launched it. This worked for me. Thanks @geynske006

Comment: I don't think this is working now. It worked earlier for me :( `alias subl='subl -a'` in the next answer is working for me.

Comment: @Anoop.P.A Thanks for you remark. Since the answer dates from the year 2013, it could be the answer isn't working anymore or there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks!

Comment: Works on ST4 on Arch Linux / KDE Plasma

Answer (score 39):

I managed to fix this problem without having to disable Sublime's last session feature (which I like & don't wish to disable). Adding a `-a` flag to the `subl` command causes files to "open in current window", which prevents subsequent windows opening.

If this solution works for you, you can avoid the need to do it every time by creating an alias (in .bashrc or equivalent):

```
alias subl='subl -a'
```

...that way you can use the `subl` command without flags and it should behave as desired. If you ever *do* want to open a folder / file in a new window, you can just add the `-n` flag: eg. `subl -n .` (open this folder in a new window).

(Credit due to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52497/16617) on the Unix Stack Exchange)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was killing me!

Comment: Wow! this is perfect. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Update for Sublime Text V4 :

```json
{
    // Mac only: This controls if an empty window is created at startup or not.
    "create_window_at_startup": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this to add new folder to the existing one:

```
subl . -a
```